How to check if an event is cancelled with AppleScript
I am using AppleScript to access calendar events and get their status for publishing elsewhere.
I can get the status of an event, and log it:
log eventStatus
(*cancelled*)

But I am unable to use this in an if statement:
if eventStatus is not "cancelled" then log "not cancelled"
(*not cancelled*)

If I try:
if eventStatus is not cancelled then log "not cancelled"

I get an error:
Result:
error "The variable cancelled is not defined." number -2753 from "cancelled"


The status is not text, it is an enumeration (see Calendar's scripting dictionary), and is not known outside the application tell statement.  You can set a regular variable based on the status and use that.

Welcome to Ask Different. I agree with red menace, we need to see more of your script to be able to assist with getting the enumeration value in a form you can use. I just used Script Debugger and it's great for assisting and learning and you get 20 days of free trial to really explore it before you only get the free parts. You might rather that for working through a problem than being specific enough that we can understand the rest of your script.
